# mongo-hadoop, how to query timestamp column in hive

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hive

select and format column is OK

`hive> select time, date(time) from user_login limit 10;
OK
2016-05-24 10:20:26 2016-05-24
2016-05-24 10:21:03 2016-05-24
2016-05-24 10:21:06 2016-05-24
2016-05-24 10:22:21 2016-05-24
2016-05-24 10:22:24 2016-05-24
2016-05-24 10:22:32 2016-05-24
2016-05-24 10:22:49 2016-05-24
2016-05-24 10:23:12 2016-05-24
2016-05-24 10:23:53 2016-05-24
2016-05-24 10:23:53 2016-05-24
Time taken: 0.084 seconds, Fetched: 10 row(s)`

but when filter on `time`, the result is empty

`hive> select time, date(time) from user_login where date(time)=date('2016-05-24') limit 10;
Query ID = tars_20160822103939_102dd35a-c11f-4ed9-a67b-d40a9c0d60ee
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1471603982720_0033, Tracking URL = http://cdh001:8088/proxy/application_1471603982720_0033/
Kill Command = /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job -kill job_1471603982720_0033
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 15; number of reducers: 0
2016-08-22 10:40:02,182 Stage-1 map = 0%, reduce = 0%
2016-08-22 10:40:37,535 Stage-1 map = 100%, reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 28.94 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 28 seconds 940 msec
Ended Job = job_1471603982720_0033
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 15 Cumulative CPU: 28.94 sec HDFS Read: 67811 HDFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 28 seconds 940 msec
OK
Time taken: 43.937 seconds
hive> select time, date(time) from user_login where date(time)='2016-05-24' limit 10;
Query ID = tars_20160822104242_394085e0-4faa-41b2-8469-cd7d3ab1a1f2
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1471603982720_0034, Tracking URL = http://cdh001:8088/proxy/application_1471603982720_0034/
Kill Command = /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job -kill job_1471603982720_0034
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 15; number of reducers: 0
2016-08-22 10:42:14,425 Stage-1 map = 0%, reduce = 0%
2016-08-22 10:42:55,860 Stage-1 map = 100%, reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 66.35 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 1 minutes 6 seconds 350 msec
Ended Job = job_1471603982720_0034
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 15 Cumulative CPU: 66.35 sec HDFS Read: 68831 HDFS Write: 60 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 1 minutes 6 seconds 350 msec
OK
NULL NULL
NULL NULL
NULL NULL
NULL NULL
NULL NULL
NULL NULL
NULL NULL
NULL NULL
NULL NULL
NULL NULL
Time taken: 49.602 seconds, Fetched: 10 row(s)`

update

### create table ddl

```
CREATE TABLE user_login
(
  tour_id STRING,
  phone STRING,
  app_id STRING,
  time TIMESTAMP
)
COMMENT 'mongodb.actionlog.user.login'
STORED BY 'com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.MongoStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES('mongo.columns.mapping'='{}')
TBLPROPERTIES('mongo.uri'='mongodb://10.252.223.34:30000/actionlog.user.login');
```

### envs

```
Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.8.0 
Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.8.0
```

Comment: can u set following config in your hive cli, `hive>set hive.fetch.task.conversion=more;` and try to execute your query

Comment: @Addy no effect
```
hive> set hive.fetch.task.conversion=more;
hive> select time, date(time) from user_login where date(time)='2016-05-24' limit 10;
OK
NULL NULL
NULL NULL
NULL NULL
NULL NULL
NULL NULL
NULL NULL
NULL NULL
NULL NULL
NULL NULL
NULL NULL
Time taken: 0.294 seconds, Fetched: 10 row(s)
hive> select time, date(time) from user_login where date(time)=date('2016-05-24') limit 10;
OK
Time taken: 0.086 seconds
hive>
```

Comment: lxneng- I do not see any issue in my environment (hive 2.0) when i executed the query, user_login  time datatype in my case was time-stamp, could you please specify your environment and the ddl for user_login ?

Comment: @Addy i just update the ddl and env, please take a look, thx.

Comment: I'v use `to_date` function resolve my problem. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:::
`select time, date(time) from user_login where date(time)=TO_DATE(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-05-24', "yyyy-MM-dd"))) limit 10`

```
hive> select time, date(time) from user_login where date(time)=TO_DATE(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-05-24', "yyyy-MM-dd"))) limit 10
OK
2016-05-24 10:20:26 2016-05-24
2016-05-24 10:21:03 2016-05-24
2016-05-24 10:21:06 2016-05-24
2016-05-24 10:22:21 2016-05-24
2016-05-24 10:22:24 2016-05-24
2016-05-24 10:22:32 2016-05-24
2016-05-24 10:22:49 2016-05-24
2016-05-24 10:23:12 2016-05-24
2016-05-24 10:23:53 2016-05-24
2016-05-24 10:23:53 2016-05-24
```